# c# replace \" characters

Tags: c#, replace, special-characters

I am sent an XML string that I'm trying to parse via an XmlReader and I'm trying to strip out the `\"` characters.

I've tried

```
.Replace(@"\", "")
.Replace("\\''", "''")
.Replace("\\''", "\"")
```

plus several other ways.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Were you trying it like this:

```
string text = GetTextFromSomewhere();
text.Replace("\\", "");
text.Replace("\"", "");
```

? If so, that's the problem - `Replace` doesn't change the *original* string, it returns a *new* string with the replacement performed... so you'd want:

```
string text = GetTextFromSomewhere();
text = text.Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"", "");
```

Note that this will replace each backslash *and* each double-quote character; if you only wanted to replace the *pair* "backslash followed by double-quote" you'd just use:

```
string text = GetTextFromSomewhere();
text = text.Replace("\\\"", "");
```

(As mentioned in the comments, this is because strings are immutable in .NET - once you've got a string object somehow, that string will always have the same contents. You can assign a reference to a *different* string to a variable of course, but that's not actually changing the contents of the existing string.)

Comment: Its a common mistake, but gets made a lot. In C# a `string` is immutable, if you change something about it, such as using the `Replace` method, it will always return a new string.

Comment: Also note that the debugger is escaping strings when displaying them. These extra backslashes can of course not be removed by `.Replace()`.

Answer (score 12):

In .NET Framework 4 and MVC this is the only representation that worked:

```
Replace(@"""","")
```

Using a backslash in whatever combination did not work...

Comment: Simple  Thnks

Answer (score 10):

Try it like this:

```
Replace("\\\"","");
```

This will replace occurrences of `\"` with empty string.

Ex:

```
string t = "\\\"the dog is my friend\\\"";
t = t.Replace("\\\"","");
```

This will result in:

```
the dog is my friend
```

Comment: Also you should get used to String.Empty instead of ""

Comment: @VoodooChild - No, it's exactly the correct amount of backslashes. See my code example for proof.

Comment: meh on string.empty.  it's the same difference.

Comment: @kurtnelle - I prefer "", there's nothing wrong with using it. I think it's less verbose than string.empty.

Comment: If he's assigning the return value, I believe this is correct. You need three backslashes, the first is used as an escape character for the second, the third is used as an escape character for the double quote. Then, of course, you need the second double quote to close out the string literal.

Comment: @dcp: well, it seems like I misread the question, I thought he only wanted to remove the backslash, but now I notice a `"` as well

Comment: Thanks! Your example helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
\ => \\ and " => \"
```

so `Replace("\\\"","")`

Answer (score 0):

Replace(@"\""", "")

You have to use double-doublequotes to [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [double-quotes](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ%3a_What_is_a_verbatim_string_literal) within a verbatim string.

Answer (score 0):

Where do these characters occur? Do you see them if you examine the XML data in, say, notepad? Or do you see them when examining the XML data in the debugger. If it is the latter, they are only escape characters for the `"` characters, and so part of the actual XML data.