# Replace substring not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, replace

I am working in asp.net mvc. want to replace `\` character to `/` character. But it is not working.
Let

```
string path="D:\Qamar\Cartoons\Image.jpg";
path=path.Replace("\","/");
```

I get error in second line. Please help how to replace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673437/c-sharp-replace-characters might help you.

Comment: _"I get error in second line."_ - it would be nice if you explained what kind of error. It's not the replace that's not working, you get a compile error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string path="D:\Qamar\Cartoons\Image.jpg";
path=path.Replace("\\","/");
```

You need to escape the backslash in the first argument for it to be treated as...a backslash (i.e. `"\\"` instead of `"\"`).

Comment: Or use `@` in front of the string to make it a verbatim string.

Comment: +1, you beat me by 20 second lol

Comment: @Raver0124: :) LOL  It happens (to me too). :}

Comment: @TiesonT.: +1 for an excellent point about another way to do it.  I just tend to be escaping-backslash happy from so much exposure to `"\0"` in C years ago. :}

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape back-slashes. The easiest way is to prefix your string with @:

```
path=path.Replace(@"\","/");
```

Another method is to escape it with another backslash:

```
path=path.Replace("\\","/");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
th=path.Replace("\\","/")
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a special escape character in string literals in c#.
You can precede the string with `@` to make it verbatim or escape the `\` with another `\`:

```
path=path.Replace(@"\","/");
```

or

```
path=path.Replace("\\","/");
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is [escape character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx), so your code will not even compile use `@` or `\\` to make the code compile. then it will work

```
string path=@"D:\Qamar\Cartoons\Image.jpg";
path=path.Replace(@"\","/");
```

or

```
string path="D:\\Qamar\\Cartoons\\Image.jpg";
path=path.Replace("\\","/");
```

but if you are working with Path or URI you can use the inbuilt C# methods to do it like below

```
System.Uri uri1 = new Uri(@"D:\Qamar\Cartoons\Image.jpg");
string whatYouWant = uri1.AbsolutePath; //Result is: "D:/Qamar/Cartoons/Image.jpg"
```