# Why Replacing \" doest not work on my case?

Tags: c#

I am doing this, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673437/c-sharp-replace-characters) :

```
string test = "test\"test";
test = test.Replace("\\\"", "");
```

but the result is still `test = "test\"test"`.

The result shoud be `test = "testtest"`, Why my replace does not work ?

Comment: literal `test\"test` is parsed by compiler and stored as `test"test`, so there is no slash in string

Comment: Not sure if flagging as a typo or not... Do note that `\"` means only `"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your string is actually `test"test` not `test\"test`. The backslash is used to escape double quote, it's not in the actual string.

Try using a verbatim string:

```
string test = @"test\""test"; // equivalent to test\\\"test
```

Comment: The verbatim string doesn't really add much.  You have to escape one of the characters either way. Without the verbatim string, it becomes `"test\\"test"`.  Regardless, you have the right of the issue - escaped string was escaped :)